# How to plot ensemble models mean?

Tags: python, average, netcdf, weather, cdo-climate

```
#read data
dset = xr.open_mfdataset('/home/users/ruoou/projects/data/cmip6/scenaromip/ssp126/tas/*'+ mod+ '*.nc', parallel=True)

#define timescale
time = dset.time
clim_set_t = dset.sel(time=slice("2015-01-16", "2100-12-16"))
clim_ta = clim_set_t['tas'].groupby('time.month').mean('time', keep_attrs=True)
clim_ta_c = (clim_ta - 273.15)

# define areas
lat = dset.lat
lon = dset.lon
lon_range = lon[(lon>60) & (lon<150)]
lat_range = lat[(lat>10) & (lat<60)]


clim_ta_c.sel(lon=lon_range, lat=lat_range, month = 1).plot.contourf(ax=ax,
                                          levels=np.arange(-30, 30 + 1, 1),
                                          transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                                          cmap='Spectral_r',
                                          cbar_kwargs={'orientation': 'vertical',     #colorbar
                                                   'label': 'temperature (℃)',
                                                   'ticks': np.arange(-30, 30 + 5, 5),
                                                   'pad': 0.05,
                                                   'shrink': 0.8})

model = dset.attrs['source_id']
title = f'{model} near-surface temperature climatology 2015-2100 (1)'
plt.title(title, fontsize = 13)
```

This is the main part of my script to plot BCC in ssp126 near-surface temperature climatology for January. [Bcc in ssp126](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT9r8.png) What should I do to add up all models and plot the mean (like average the BCC in ssp126 and IPSL in ssp126)? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: I would use Adrian Tompkins answer below. Though, if you are asking a question about averaging CMIP6 files you really should specify whether the time steps and grids are the same in each file. Otherwise the answer could be missing a number of steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged the question `cdo-climate`, so I presume you are also happy to have a `cdo` based solution, I added a remapping step, but check out [remapping questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61806343/regrid-netcdf-file-in-python) on stackoverflow, or my [remapping video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79o6DXr_3zM) for more details.

```
dir=/home/users/ruoou/projects/data/cmip6/scenaromip/ssp126/tas/
# remap all files to a 1x1 deg grid 
for file in $dir/*modelname*.nc ; do 
   cdo remapbil,r360x180 $file ${file%???}_remap.nc 
done 
# calculate ens mean
cdo ensmean *_remap.nc ensmean.nc
```

then you can open `ensmean.nc` and plot it as you wish.

Comment: Upvoted. Though based on the question the files likely have different grids, so another step might be missing

Comment: `from cdo import Cdo

from cdo import *  
cdo = Cdo()  
nc_ensmean = cdo.ensmean(input = '/home/users/ruoou/projects/data/cmip6/scenaromip/ssp126/tas/*.nc', output = 'nc_ensmean.nc')  

CDOException: (returncode:1) Warning (cdfInqContents): Coordinates variable time can't be assigned!  
Warning (cdfInqContents): Coordinates variable time can't be assigned!  
cdo    ensmean (Abort): Grid size of the input parameter tas do not match!`  
Just as Robert said, the grids are different, so it shown the error notification. But thank you all the same.

Comment: Then you need to map all fields to a common grid first, e.g. cdo remapbil,r360x180 in.nc out.nc