# Unexpected behaviour when chunking with multiple netcdf files in xarray/dask

Tags: python, dask, netcdf, python-xarray, chunking

I'm working with a set of 468 netcdf files summing up to 12GB in total. Each file has only one global snapshot of a geophysical variable, i.e. for each file the data shape is `(1, 1801, 3600)` corresponding to dimensions `('time', 'latitude', 'longitude')`.

My RAM is 8GB so I need chunking. I'm creating a xarray dataset using `xarray.open_mfdataset` and I have found that using the parameter chunk when calling `xarray.open_mfdataset` or doing a rechunking after with method `.chunk` has totally different outcomes. A similar issues was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838873/performance-of-chunking-in-xarray-dask-when-opening-and-re-chunking-a-dataset) without getting any response.

From the xarray documentation, chunking when calling `xarray.open_dataset` or when rechunking with `.chunk` should be exactly equivalent...

http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html
[image]

...but it doesn't seem so. I share here my examples.

**1) CHUNKING WHEN CALLING `xarray.open_mfdataset` ALONG THE SPATIAL DIMENSIONS (longitude, latitude) HAVING THE TIME DIMENSION UNCHUNKED.**

```
import xarray as xr

data1 = xr.open_mfdataset('/data/cds_downloads/2m_temperature/*.nc',
                          concat_dim='time', combine='nested',
                          chunks = {'longitude':400, 'latitude':200}) \
                         .chunk({'time':-1})
data1.t2m.data
```

[image]

```
with ProgressBar():
    data1.std('time').compute()

[########################################] | 100% Completed |  5min 44.1s
```

In this case everything works fine.

**2) CHUNKING WITH METHOD `.chunk` ALONG THE SPATIAL DIMENSIONS (longitude, latitude) HAVING THE TIME DIMENSION UNCHUNKED.**

```
data2=xr.open_mfdataset('/data/cds_downloads/2m_temperature/*.nc',
                        concat_dim='time',combine='nested') \
                       .chunk({'time': -1, 'longitude':400, 'latitude':200})
data2.t2m.data
```

[image]

As this image shows, apparently the chunking is now exactly the same than in 1). However...

```
with ProgressBar():
    data2.std('time').compute()

[#####################################   ] | 93% Completed |  1min 50.8s
```

...the computation of the std could not finish, the jupyter notebook kernel died without message due to exceeding the memory limit as I could checked monitoring with `htop`... This likely implies that the chunking was indeed not taking place in reality and all the dataset without chunks is being loaded in to memory.

**3) CHUNKING WHEN CALLING `xarray.open_mfdataset` ALONG THE SPATIAL DIMENSIONS (longitude, latitude) AND LEAVING THE TIME DIMENSION CHUNKED BY DEFAULT (ONE CHUNK PER FILE).**

In theory this case should be much slower that 1) since the computation of `std` is done along the time dimension and thus much more chunks are generated unnecessarily (421420 chunks now vs 90 chunks in (1)).

```
data3 = xr.open_mfdataset('/data/cds_downloads/2m_temperature/*.nc',
                          concat_dim='time', combine='nested',
                          chunks = {'longitude':400, 'latitude':200})
data3.t2m.data
```

[image]

```
with ProgressBar():
    data3.std('time').compute()

[########################################] | 100% Completed |  5min 51.2s
```

However there is no memory problems and the amount of time required for the computation is almost the same than in case 1). This again suggests that method `.chunk` seems to be not working properly.

Anyone knows if this makes sense or how to solve this issue? I would need to be able to change the chunking depending on the specific computation I need to do.

Thanks

PD: I'm using xarray version 0.15.1

Comment: I have tested using xr.open_dataset with one single and large netcdf file (instead of a set of hundreds of smaller netcdf files) and the same issue appears. Method .chunk does not seem to have a noticeable impact on the performance.

Comment: I found something similar with chunking on open_mfdataset versus after. This first was slower I think but I couldn't really pin it down, plus I was just starting to learn xarray. My current approach is not to bother chunking during the open (as nothing's really read in yet?) and chunk after, especially when removing the time chunks .chunk({'time':-1}. That seemed to have a big effect for some reason. Then I use .persist() or .compute() which is when things really happen.

Comment: So, @Paul you mean in your case using .chunk after calling open_mfdataset has a clear impact on performance when computing? I would be quite surprise if that is the case. The working solution I have found is the opposite; Simply forget about .chunk and create different datarray object calling open_mfdataset with different values passed to the chunk parameter within. This really seems to work fine in my case.

Comment: Just a later additonal possibly helpful comment; all these difficult to understand and apparent inconsistencies are not found when using the file format zarr which consistently behaves as the expected and indicated chunking and also it is usually much more faster than netcdf

Answer (score 0):

> I would need to be able to change the chunking depending on the specific computation I need to do.

Yes, computations will be highly sensitive to chunk structure.

Chunking as early as possible in a computation (ideally when you're reading in data) is ideal because that makes the overall computation simpler.

In general I recommend larger chunk sizes.  See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#avoid-very-large-graphs